# QT 5.15.11 installer

Tags: qt, qt-installer, qt5.15

How to get installers for Qt version 5.15.11 or similar?
I know that 5.15.x is a LTS branch and the latest patches are sent only to the ones with a commercial license. But I saw that sources for other releases are available, but I cannot find installers of them for any platform.
I am supposed to build them from source or have they been published somewhere I am missing?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Granted you know you should not be using Qt 5.15 anymore, you can use the maintenance tool to download the sources or if it is your first time downloading Qt, you can get it from [this page](https://www.qt.io/download) (open source link I suppose).

Comment: Qt is not that difficult to compile from source. At work I have done it more than a hundred times over the years. We started using Qt in 2008 for development of our applications for medical imaging research. With that said you do need to install python, perl and I believe ruby. Also vcpkg may still have it in the current ports. The last time I compiled Qt I used vcpkg before that we had our own CMake based tool that scripted the build.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you must compile it from source yourself. The source code is available in Qt archives https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.15/.

As the [README](https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.15/5.15.0/OFFLINE_README.txt) states:

```
Due to The Qt Company offering changes, open source offline installers are not available any more since Qt 5.15. Read more about offering changes in the https://www.qt.io/blog/qt-offering-changes-2020 blog.

If you need offline installers, please consider our new Qt for Small Business offering: https://www.qt.io/blog/available-now-qt-for-small-businesses
```

The offline installers are not provided anymore since version 5.15. But they are available in the same archive link for 5.14 and earlier.

I believe 5.15.2 is still available in the online installer though. But not the 5.15.11 your requested, that you must compile yourself.